# Cannot Instantiate the type Shape. I have already changed the class header to extends Shape. Keep getting the same error

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I keep getting the error cannot instantiate the type Shape. I have changed the class header to public class ShapeDriver extends Shape. Still same error. My assignment requires me to write inheritance code that will display 3 different shapes in the console of Eclipse. I keep getting this error in my code when I try to run it but I cannot figure out what is wrong. Any tips or guidance would be appreciated.

**ShapeDriver.java**

```
package shape;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.*;

    public class ShapeDriver extends Shape {
        public static void start() throws FileNotFoundException{

            Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
            String fileName;
            ArrayList<Shape> shapes;

            System.out.println("Enter a file name: ");
            fileName= input.next();

            shapes = create(fileName); // calls create that returns a list of shapes.
            display(shapes); // calls display to print the list of shapes in order.

            input.close();
        }

        private static ArrayList<Shape> create(String fileName) {

            return null;
        }

        private static void display(ArrayList<Shape> shapes) {

        }

        /**
         * Tests all methods in Shape design.
         * @param args A reference to a string array containing command-line
         * arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args){

            //Creates at least two shape objects.
            Shape shape1 = new Shape();
            Shape shape2 = new Shape();     

            //Retrieves the name of first shape, and store it in memory.
            System.out.println("Shape1: " + shape1.getName());

            //Print the name of the first shape.
            System.out.println("Shape1");

            //Changes the name of the first shape.
            shape1.setName("shape1.");


            //Retrieves the name of first shape again, store it in memory.
            System.out.println("Shape1: " + shape1.getName());

            //Print the name of the first shape again.
            System.out.println("Shape1");

            //Print first shape object.
            System.out.println(shape1);

            //Print other shape objects.
            System.out.println(shape2);

            //Compares the first shape with itself, print the results.
            System.out.println("Shape1 is equal to shape1: " + shape1.equals(shape1));
            //Compares the first shape with another shape, print the results.
            System.out.println("Shape1 is equal to shape2: " + shape1.equals(shape2));

            //Compares the first shape with a String object, print the result
            System.out.println("Shape1 is equal to string hello: " + shape1.equals(new String("Hello")) );
        }

        @Override
        public double area() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

**Shape.java**

```
package shape;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public abstract class Shape {

// Declare variables
DecimalFormat shapeDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

/**
 * The name of this shape
 */
private String name;

/***
 * Returns the area of this shape.
 * @return The area of this shape.
 */

public abstract double area();

/**
 *  Constructs a shape with default name.
 */

public Shape(){
        name = this.getClass().getName();

}

/**
 * Returns the name of this shape.
 * @param
 */

public Shape(String name){
        this.name = name;
}

/**
 * Returns the name of this shape.
 * 
 * @return A string specifying the name of this shape.
 */

public String getName(){
        return name;

} 

/**
 * Constructs a shape with a specific name.
 * @param name  The name of this shape
 */

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;

} 

/**
 * Indicates if this shape is "equal to" some other object. If the other object
 * is not a shape, return false. If the other object is a * shape, and has the
 * same name, return true.
 * 
 * @param obj An Object reference to a specific object
 * @return A boolean value specifying whether this shape is equal to some other
 *         object
 */

public boolean equals(Shape obj){
    if (obj.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(name) == 0)
        return true;
else
        return false;

}

/**
 * Returns a string representation of this shape containing the type * and
 * hidden values.
 * 
 * @return A string representation of this shape
 */

public String toString(){
    return "\n Shape: " + name + " Area = " + shapeDecimalFormat.format(area());

     } 

}
```

Comment: `Shape shape1 = new Shape();` Shape is declared as abstract.  You can't make one, period.

Comment: You have not fully understood your assignment. You need to implement three different classes that extend Shape. Circle, Square, Triangle ... Something like that. As stated by markspace, you cannot instantiate an abstract class.

Comment: @RubioRic I already implemented the three different classes that extend Shape. (Circle,Triangle,Rectangle) and created a driver for them. I just didn't show them here on this thread. I just stuck on this part

Comment: Just change new Shape by new Circle and new Triangle. I think that is one of the assignment goal